# Android widget - Where to register for explicit broadcasts

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-widget

Working on an Android widget that needs to be able to receive a broadcast from my application installed on the device itself. Basically want to be able to to notify the widget/s when certain events occur so they can update rather than wait the full 30 minutes.

Custom action: "com.example.UPDATE"

It looks like static register isn't an option anymore for my widget to receive custom intent broadcasts from my main application since they are separate entities and from the documentation it looks like Google locked down what is possible with static registers.  I wouldn't want to specific a single receiver anyways as I would like to be able to support multiple widgets and each receive the broadcast if they need to.

What would be the right way to dynamically register a broadcast receiver for a widget's context?

Would I register it in the onUpdate function of my AppWidgetProvider and just make sure its registered each time the onUpdate gets called?  That provides a context I could register it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Working on an Android widget that needs to be able to receive a broadcast from my application installed on the device itself.

You act as though there are two separate apps: the "real" app and a separate app for the app widget. I strongly encourage you not to go that route, and instead have a single app. In that case, your app can simply use `AppWidgetManager` when it wishes to update the app widget's UI.

If you are convinced that having two separate apps is the right approach, read on.

> It looks like static register isn't an option anymore for my widget to receive custom intent broadcasts from my main application since they are separate entities and from the documentation it looks like Google locked down what is possible with static registers

Only for implicit broadcasts. In your case, you can use an explicit broadcast, where you identify the specific app or component to receive the broadcast. `setPackage()` on the `Intent` should be sufficient.

> What would be the right way to dynamically register a broadcast receiver for a widget's context?

Implement a foreground service and have it register for the broadcasts. It can then use `AppWidgetManager` to update your app widget. Since users will not like this, I recommend that you not go this route.

> Would I register it in the onUpdate function of my AppWidgetProvider and just make sure its registered each time the onUpdate gets called?

No, because your process will go away shortly after `onUpdate()` returns, if there is nothing keeping that process around, such as a foreground service. This is why using a manifest-registered receiver and an explicit broadcast is a better solution.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  

So I'm thinking of them as separate apps mostly in terms of updating.  Rather than having the AppWidgetManager notify each of the app widgets, I was thinking of letting it broadcast instead.  Is it more correct to keep track of all widget Ids and then loop through and notify them all?  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.  It looks like all of the functions want remote views or ids for what to update, which my main app wouldn't know?


Example:  I want to notify the widgets when user logs out out the app.

Comment: I think you sold me on using AppWidgetManager.  I am just a little confused on how to notify the widget by id only and just let it run through its regular update process, same as if it had hit its 30min update timer.

Comment: @Kyle: An app widget is not an actual thing, from a programming standpoint. What you were suggesting is akin to "notifying" a `Boolean` or a `String`. An app widget really is just a set of IDs, for which you push `RemoteViews`. An `AppWidgetProvider` is just a set of callbacks that you can use to maintain your copy of the list of IDs and to update the `RemoteViews` when the OS wants it (independent of any pushes that you may want to do). "which my main app wouldn't know" -- move your build-the-`RemoteViews` logic into a class that can be used both by the `AppWidgetProvider` and elsewhere.

Comment: Got it.  Ok think i'm finally getting this, appreciate all of the info.  Is it normal for a particular widget to have multiple ids?

Testing out this:

 val widgetIds = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
                    .getAppWidgetIds(ComponentName(context, MySpecificWidgetProvider::class.java))

It seems to return 2 ids for this particular widget.  This provider just supports 1 widget currently.

Comment: @Kyle: "Is it normal for a particular widget to have multiple ids?... This provider just supports 1 widget currently" -- I am not certain what you mean. AFAIK, there is one ID per instance of the app widget. Users can add multiple instance of the app widget to the screen. For some app widgets, they specifically support that and let the user configure different data for each (e.g., weather forecasts for separate cities). Other app widgets don't have different data per app widget, in which case they just update them all with the same `RemoteViews`.

Comment: @Kyle: So, if you're saying that you only have one instance of the app widget on your home screen, but you are getting two IDs... the only scenarios I can think of for that is if you have multiple device users (and each had an instance), or some sort of bug somewhere. But, it has been a while since I fussed much with app widgets in depth, so there may be other scenarios that I'm forgetting.

Comment: It was a really dumb error on my side.  I had somehow/at some point dragged a widget onto one of the other swiped over home screens.  So while I was only seeing my one on the main screen, I did actually have a second instance in existence.  Thanks for all the help, finally getting a grasp on how to work with these widgets.